# Encrypt and decrypt files in Python

Tags: python, file, encryption

I'm doing a project in which I need to encrypt files, copy them to another folder and be able to decrypt them with another .py

The thing is, I see a lot of examples, but none works... I guess I'm doing something wrong, obviously, so here I am asking for guidance.

Code I used to generate a key (this works):

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided = 'password'
password = password_provided.encode()

salt = b"\xb9\x1f|}'S\xa1\x96\xeb\x154\x04\x88\xf3\xdf\x05"

kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=salt,
            iterations=100000,
            backend=default_backend())

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
# print(key)
with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
    key_file.write(key)
```

And here is the problem. This is my code for encrypting a file, but it gives me the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted'`

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

file = open('key.key', 'rb')
key = file.read()
file.close

with open('DocumentoEncriptado.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

fernet = Fernet(key)
encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

with open('DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted', 'rb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted)
```

Comment: Open the DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted document with the "write" flag, not the "read" flag: open('DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted', 'wb')

Comment: Oh my, that was it and I didn't see the typo! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the line:

```
with open('DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted', 'rb') as f:
```

You are trying to read file "DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted", because the FileMode is 
set to 'rb'.
And it seems that there's no file with that name.
You just need to change FileMode to 'wb'.
 So it becomes like this

```
 with open('DocumentoEncriptado.txt.encrypted', 'wb') as f:
```